# Picasso - will the memory cache be released?

Tags: android, memory, picasso

As I know Picasso by default takes 15% of available app memory to cache images. Will the cached memory be freed when other parts of my application needs additional memory? In other case I'd like Picasso cached memory to have "lower priority" than rest of my app.

Comment: If you're running out of memory because of that 15% you have other problems.

Comment: @CharlesDurham It is rather theoretical question then appearing problem. I'm using Picasso only with one list in one activity. I don't need this cached images in rest of 95% my app functionality. So I'm just wondering if it is worth to "waste" 15% of memory.

Comment: I highly doubt it works the way you're thinking. It looks like Picasso is just using an LruCache. That class isn't going to do anything if your app starts using more memory. You'll just end up OOM. 

Further, your app is already allocated the memory, using it isn't a "waste". In fact, not using it **is** a waste.